# Read response body in squid

Tags: proxy, squid

Is there a way to view/read the response body squid forwarded to one of the clients?

Comment: It would be useful to know why. If it is debug, the responses below are probably adequate (tcpdump/wireshark). If not...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about getting a live view of the response, you can simply use a network sniffer like `tcpdump` on the proxy server and filter using the client IP address.

Answer (score 0):

On a per basis the response body would not be saved on the server so you would have to catch it with wireshark or tcpdump. I don't think it is stored there but check the log files. and maybe your config to see if you can up the log files to include more info maybe a debug mode.